Retag single-tagged [any-jurisdiction] and [multiple-jurisdiction] Questions
This community has reached a consensus to remove the [any-jurisdiction] tag and the [multiple-jurisdiction] tag from Law SE.
Because there are over 250 questions with those tags (combined) we are NOT asking the community to burninate these tags before we block them, staff can do that on the backend. However, if I did this right now there would be at least a handful of questions left untagged (because they currently only have one tag, and its one of these two).
So I am asking the community if you can take on the project of finding any questions tagged with ONLY any-jurisdiction or multiple-jurisdiction and retagging them with something more appropriate. Once that is done we can move forward with the burnination and blocking of the tags.
Let me know here if there are any questions or concerns, or if you are able to help out with this effort!

There are no longer any questions tagged only with any-jurisdiction or only with multiple-jurisdiction

These two tags have now been bulk removed and blocked on Law SE.
